# Splitting a list into groups determined by grouping of another list

Tags: python, list, grouping

Say I have two lists

```
a = [True, True, True, False, False, True, False]
b = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

I can group one list into similar items:

```
import itertools
b =  [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(a)]
>>> [[True, True, True], [False, False], [True], [False]]
```

Is there a convenient way to apply this operation to the other list to give:

```
>>> [[1,2,1], [3,2], [1], [0]]
```

This works but is there something nicer:?

```
new_list = []
index = 0
for i in b:
    length = len(i)
    new_list.append(y[index:index+length])
    index += length
```

Thanks

Comment: Choosing boolean values is a bad idea, I guess. I am totally failing to see the pattern. Can you atleast post the expected output?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, the expected out put is [[1,2,1], [3,2], [1], [0]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` on `enumerate(a)`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> indices = ((x[0] for x in g) for _, g in groupby(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1)))
>>> [[b[x] for x in lst] for lst in indices]
[[1, 2, 1], [3, 2], [1], [0]]
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use the same indices reference but on n number of lists? e.g. [[list1[y] for y in lst] for lst in indices], [[list2[y] for y in lst] for lst in indices] etc.. I get an empty list when I try using the same reference on more than one list!

Comment: Having said that, it works nicely as a function:
    def indices(ref): return ((x[0] for x in g) for _, g in groupby(enumerate(ref), key=itemgetter(1))), then [[anylist[x] for x in lst] for lst in indices(ref)]

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby, izip
groups = [list(grp) for _, grp in groupby(izip(a, b), lambda x: x[0])]
print [[number for _, number in items] for items in groups]
# [[1, 2, 1], [3, 2], [1], [0]]
```